# NDSolveValue stiff system error

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

I have two equations involving elliptical integrals (`equat1` and `equat2` in the code below). My goal is to obtain plots of `u[o]` and `d[o]`. I turn my equations into ODE with initial conditions found using `FindRoot`. While trying to solve my ODE with `NDSolveValue`,I encounter the error:

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At o == 0.259506989709951`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

However, I expect a smooth curve as my solution. I tried to do a series expansion of the elliptical integrals and it worked. The solutions were smooth curve. However, as I include higher orders in the expansion, I encounter the same error again. I tried increasing the `WorkingPrecesion`and changing the `Method`option. Probably `StiffnessSwitching` will help, but I did not manage to make it work. Any ideas on how I should proceed?

```
lambda1[u_, o_, d_] := (u - o)/d;
lambda2[u_, o_, d_] := (-u - o)/d;

k1sq[u_, o_, d_] := (Sqrt[1 + ((lambda1[u, o, d])^2)] + 
lambda1[u, o, d])/(2*(Sqrt[1 + ((lambda1[u, o, d])^2)]));

k2sq[u_, o_, d_] := (Sqrt[1 + ((lambda2[u, o, d])^2)] + 
 lambda2[u, o, d])/(2*(Sqrt[1 + ((lambda2[u, o, d])^2)]));

a1[u_, o_, d_] := (1 + (lambda1[u, o, d])^2)^(1/4);
a2[u_, o_, d_] := (1 + (lambda2[u, o, d])^2)^(1/4);
b1[u_, o_, d_] := Sqrt[1 + (lambda1[u, o, d])^2] + lambda1[u, o, d];
b2[u_, o_, d_] := Sqrt[1 + (lambda2[u, o, d])^2] + lambda2[u, o, d];

equat1[u_, o_, d_, e_] = (2/3)*(((e)/d)^(3/2)) == ((lambda1[u, o, d]*a1[u, o, d]*
EllipticE[k1sq[u, o, d]]) - ((lambda1[u, o, d]*
EllipticK[k1sq[u, o, d]])/(2*a1[u, o, d]*b1[u, o, d])) +
((EllipticK[k1sq[u, o, d]])/(2*a1[u, o, d])) - 
(lambda2[u, o, d]*a2[u, o, d]*EllipticE[k2sq[u, o, d]]) + 
((lambda2[u, o, d]*EllipticK[k2sq[u, o, d]])/(2*a2[u, o, d]*
 b2[u, o, d])) - ((EllipticK[k2sq[u, o, d]])/(2*a2[u, o, d])));

tlambda1[u_, d_] := u/d;
tlambda2[u_, d_] := -u/d;

tk1sq[u_, d_] := (Sqrt[1 + ((tlambda1[u, d])^2)] + 
 tlambda1[u, d])/(2*(Sqrt[1 + ((tlambda1[u, d])^2)]));

tk2sq[u_, d_] := (Sqrt[1 + ((tlambda2[u, d])^2)] + 
 tlambda2[u, d])/(2*(Sqrt[1 + ((tlambda2[u, d])^2)]));

ta1[u_, d_] := (1 + (tlambda1[u, d])^2)^(1/4);
ta2[u_, d_] := (1 + (tlambda2[u, d])^2)^(1/4);
tb1[u_, d_] := Sqrt[1 + (tlambda1[u, d])^2] + tlambda1[u, d];
tb2[u_, d_] := Sqrt[1 + (tlambda2[u, d])^2] + tlambda2[u, d];

equat2[u_, o_, d_] = Sqrt[d]*(((lambda1[u, o, d])*
EllipticK[k1sq[u, o, d]]/(2*a1[u, o, d])) - (a1[u, o, d]*
EllipticE[k1sq[u, o, d]]) + ((EllipticK[k1sq[u, o, d]])/(2*a1[u, o, d]*
b1[u, o, d])) + ((lambda2[u, o, d])*EllipticK[k2sq[u, o, d]]/(2*a2[u,o,d]))- 
(a2[u, o, d]*EllipticE[k2sq[u, o, d]]) + 
((EllipticK[k2sq[u,o,d]])/(2*a2[u,o, d]*
b2[u, o, d]))) == (Sqrt[1]*(((tlambda1[u, d])*
EllipticK[tk1sq[u, d]]/(2*ta1[u, d])) - (ta1[u, d]*
EllipticE[tk1sq[u, d]]) + ((EllipticK[tk1sq[u, d]])/(2*ta1[u, d]*
tb1[u, d])) + ((tlambda2[u, d])*EllipticK[tk2sq[u, d]]/(2*ta2[u, d])) - 
(ta2[u, d]*EllipticE[tk2sq[u, d]]) + ((EllipticK[tk2sq[u, d]])/(2*ta2[u, d]*
 tb2[u, d]))));

{dj, uj} = {d, u} /. FindRoot[{equat2[u, o, d], equat1[u, o, d, .1]} /. 
 o -> 0, {{d, .5}, {u, .1}}];

{dsolj, usolj} = NDSolveValue[{D[equat2[u, o, d] /. {d -> d[o], u -> u[o]}, o], 
D[equat1[u, o, d, .1] /. {d -> d[o], u -> u[o]}, o], u[0] == uj, d[0] == dj}, {d, u}, 
{o, 0, 1}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]

Plot[{dsolj[t], usolj[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}]
```

Comment: that appears to simply be the nature of the system, it is singular around `.259`.  You can get it to run margially further with  `MaxStepSize -> .0001`

Comment: Shouldn't the question be how to determine whether there is stiffness or a singularity?  If there's not supposed to be a singularity, but in fact there is one in the coded system, then that seems an important clue.

Answer (score 4):

There's a singularity in the ODE. Perhaps you're thinking `d` as a function of `u` is smooth.  Here's a picture of the vector field of the ODE.  The solution runs right up to where the vector changes direction (turns from red to green).  It seems that as a *direction field*, the field is smooth, but the vector changes orientation because the derivative of `o` is always `1` and the o-d components rotate past vertical (in the projection onto the o-d plane).

```
sys = {D[equat2[u, o, d] /. {d -> d[o], u -> u[o]}, o], 
  D[equat1[u, o, d, .1] /. {d -> d[o], u -> u[o]}, o], u[0] == uj, 
  d[0] == dj}

phasefield = First@Solve[sys[[{1, 2}]], D[Through[{u, d}[o]], o]];

vplot = VectorPlot3D[
   {1, d'[o], u'[o]} /. phasefield /. (f_)[o] :> f // Evaluate,
   {o, -0.03, 1}, {d, 0.065, 1.}, {u, 0., 0.15},
   VectorScale -> {Small, 0.2, 1 &}, AxesLabel -> {o, d, u},
   VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   VectorColorFunction -> 
    Function[{o, d, u, vo, vd, vu, n}, 
     Darker@Hue[1/2 + ArcTan[vd, vu]/(2 Pi)]]];

Show[
 vplot,
 ParametricPlot3D[{o, dsolj[o], usolj[o]},
  {o, 0, 0.2595069897099519`}, 
  PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[4], Blue}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is a slice of the vector field showing the reversal of the vectors at the point where `NDSolve` stopped integrating.

```
Show[vplot, ParametricPlot3D[{o, dsolj[o], usolj[o]},
  {o, 0, 0.2595069897099519`}, 
  PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[4], Blue}],
 PlotRange -> {All, All, {0.085, 0.13}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Gosh, these images look horrible today. They're from the SE Uploader, Image(pp).  They don't look nearly so bad on my screen.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `NDSolve` applied to the total derivatives of `equat1` and `equat2`, as in the question, one can solve the two equations simultaneously with `FindRoot`.  The result is

```
Table[Values@FindRoot[{equat2[u, o, d], equat1[u, o, d, .1]} , {{d, .5}, {u, .1}}], 
    {o, 0, .26, .001}];
ListPlot[Transpose@%, DataRange -> {0, .26}, Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {o, "d, u"}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

which is indistinguishable from the `NDSolve` results.  Simply stated, `FindRoot` can find no real roots for `o > 0.259507154261615`.  It is for this reason that `NDSolve`, as employed in the question, fails at

```
dsolj["Domain"][[1, 2]]    
(* 0.259506989709951` *)
```

Incidentally, experimentation suggests that there are no real roots for larger `o`, at least as far as `o == 1`.